# PHP : Getting each value from the array and calculate

Tags: php, arrays

I have these values in the `array`=`Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 2 [2] => 10 [3] => 5 )`

How do i get each value separately from the `array` and perform the below calculation?

```
$j=$q*100/$ytot;
```

And this is what i've tried so far, which isnt giving the correct value :

```
$resul=mysql_query("select * from post_bet where bet_id = '$id'")or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($resul)>0)
{
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($resul))
    {
        $y_uid=$row['yes_userid'];          
        $y_uamt=$row['yes_useramount'];
        $n_uid=$row['no_userid'];
        $n_uamt=$row['no_useramount'];
        $ytot=$row['yes_total'];
        $ntot=$row['no_total'];
        $hhh=explode(',',$row['yes_useramount']);
        $q = print_r($hhh);
        echo $j=$q*100/$ytot;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you want here ? Do you want to perform the operation for each array values or you want to append the operation to a single variable $j

Comment: Yessir! i do want to calculate each value. Ignore my mistakes please.

Comment: You need to specify what you mean with the calculation. What are `$j`, `$q`, and `$ytot`?

Comment: As far as I can tell from your code you are fetching an associative array from  MySQL database that looks nothing like the array you describe in your question. This is unclear. Please clear it up.

Comment: how u can do like that? $hhh can only store 1 value and you should place exploit outside the while loop. you did wrong.

Comment: what will be the output of $row['yes_useramount'] ? or else show us you table with sample data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
$resul=mysql_query("select * from post_bet where bet_id = '$id'")or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($resul)>0)
{
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($resul))
    {
        $y_uid=$row['yes_userid'];          
        $y_uamt=$row['yes_useramount'];
        $n_uid=$row['no_userid'];
        $n_uamt=$row['no_useramount'];
        $ytot=$row['yes_total'];
        $ntot=$row['no_total'];
        $hhh=explode(',',$row['yes_useramount']);

    }


foreach($hhh as $val)
{
        echo $j=$val*100/$ytot;
}
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. This is what i wanted. THANKS! \m/

Answer (score 1):

A simple `foreach` should do the trick:

```
foreach (explode(',', $row['yes_useramount']) as $q) {
    echo $q * 100 / $ytot;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can process an array in PHP using `foreach` like shown below:

```
foreach (($hhh) as $v => $k)
{
echo $k*100/$ytot;
}
```

Here,

```
$hhh=explode(',',$row['yes_useramount']);
```

So `$hhh` will return an array of values from `$row['yes_useramount']` which was imploded with `,`.

Comment: Cool. But how do i get each value of the `array` after a `,` ? `implode` doesn't seem to work here.

Answer (score 0):

try this code in your script. If there having error please tell me here.

```
$resul=mysql_query("select * from post_bet where bet_id = '$id'")or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($resul)>0)
{
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($resul))
{
 $y_uid=$row['yes_userid'];         
 $y_uamt[]=$row['yes_useramount'];
 $n_uid=$row['no_userid'];
 $n_uamt=$row['no_useramount'];
 $ytot=$row['yes_total'];
 $ntot=$row['no_total'];
}

for($i = 0; $i<count($y_uamt);$i++){

$sum_uamt = $sum_uamt + int($y_uamt[$i]);
}

echo $j = $sum_uamt * 100 / $ytot;
```

Comment: echo isn't returning any values.

Comment: u try echo $y_aumt inside while loop.